# Modify route of API controller to remove "API" from the controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-web-api2

I have two controllers for my `User` model. One is a regular MVC controller which handles the views and inherits from `Controller`. Then I have an API controller which inherits from `ApiController`. Their names are `UsersController` and `UsersApiController` respectively. I wish to remove from "Api" from the API controller's URL so I can type:

> www.mywebsite.com/api/Users

rather than:

> www.mywebsite.com/api/UsersApi

which contains a redundant "api".

I have tried applying the attribute `[Route("Users")]` and `[Route("api/Users")]` to the entire controller but neither work and they seem to just break it. My `WebApiConfig.cs` has the default route config.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use Attribute routing.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersApiController : ApiController
{  
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() 
    { 

    }
}
```

You should be able to customize it per action methods as well

```
public class UsersApiController : ApiController
{  
    [Route("api/users")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() 
    { 

    }
}
```